# Removing column from data.frame then creating new column with similar name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have just encountered a weird issue in R version 3.1.3 and RStudio Version 0.98.1091 (it may have been present in previous versions).

I have a **test** data.frame of proteins with many columns, one of which is called **"Peptide.IDs"** and lists IDs from an old, obsolete peptides file. Those IDs are listed as a semicolon-separated character string. Because I have instead created my own peptides file with different IDs, I removed that column:

```
test$Peptide.IDs <- NULL
```

then I created a new column to compile my own IDs as a list:

```
test$Peptide.IDs.list <- sapply(test$Evidence.IDs.list, function(x) {x <- unlist(temp2$Peptide.ID[which(temp2$id %in% x)])
                                                                x <- unique(x)
                                                                })
```

However, when I then try to "ctrl+Enter" the text **test$Peptide.IDs**, instead of returning **NULL** as normal, Rstudio displays the contents of **test$Peptide.IDs.list**, i.e. a list.

So it seems like R is using the partial column name from an old, obsolete column, to call a newer column instead.

Comment: Claims about potential bugs without reproducible examples don't carry much weight. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug.  It is expected behavior.

The "problem" is that the `$` operator allows a partial, leading match, if it is unique.  In your case, `Peptide.IDs` matches `Peptide.IDs.list` only, as assigning `NULL` to a column **removes** the column from the data frame.

```
> d <- data.frame(a = 1)
> d$a.a <- 2
> d$a <- NULL   # Removes column `a`, leaving only `a.a`
> d$a           # column `a.a` is retrieved
[1] 2
```

To not have this issue, use the `[[` operator instead of `$`.  It does not perform partial matches:

```
> d[['a']]   # Not found returns NULL
NULL
> d[['a.a']]
[1] 2
```